# How to determine if a current set of data values represent or relate to previous historic data values?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

I am trying to develop an method to identify browsing pattern of a user on the basis of page requests.
In a simple example I have created 8 pages and for each page request from the user to the page I have stored that page's request frequency in the database as you can see below:[image]

Now, my hypothesis is to identify the difference in the page request pattern, which leads to my assumption that if the pattern differs from pre-existing one then its a different (fraudulent) user. I am trying to develop this method as a part of an Multifactor-Authentication system.

Now when a user logs in and browses with a different pattern from the ones observed previously, the system should be able to identify it as a change in pattern.

Question is how to utilize these data values to check if current pattern relates to pre-existing patterns or not.

Comment: give an example of a fraudulent behavior

Comment: for the above data set, a fraudulent session would consist of page request frequencies like: 90,10,0,0,0,400,20,1

Comment: In that case you should calculate the total page visits and compare them. In non-fraud cases it looks like the average is around 3-4. Bu, in your fraud case the average is much higher.

Comment: Essentially you need to create "features" (like total page visits) that will help you. It is not a one-off process. It will take many iteration and lots of domain knowledge to create a set of useful "features"

Comment: I will take that as an possible solution, but I was wondering if there are some distinct well defined methods, that are usually used to solve these kind of problems. Anyways,thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's a pretty simple idea (and basically, what you're looking to do is generate a set of features, then identify if the current session behaviour is different to the previously observed behaviour). I like to think of these one-class problems (only normal behaviour to train on, want to detect significant departure) as density estimation problems, so here's a simple probability model which will allow you to get the probability of a current request pattern. Basically, when this gets too low (and how low that is will be something you need to tune for the desired behaviour), something is going on.

Our observations consist of counts for each of the pages. Let their sum, the total number of requests, be equal to c_total, and counts for each page *i* be p_i. Then I'd propose:

c_total ~ Poisson(\lambda)

p|c_total ~ Multinomial(\theta, c_total)

This allows you to assign probability to a new observation given learned user-specific parameters \lambda (uni-variate) and \theta (vector of same dimension as p). To do this, calculate the probability of seeing that many requests from the pmf of the Poisson distribution, then calculate the probability of seeing the page counts from the multinomial, and multiply them together. You probably then want to normalise by c_total so that you can compare sessions with different numbers of requests (since the more requests, the more numbers < 1 you're multiplying together).

So, all that's left is to get the parameters from previous, "good" sessions from that user. The simplest thing is maximum likelihood, where \lambda is the mean total number of requests in previous sessions, and \theta_i is the proportion of all page views which were p_i (for that particular user). This may work for you: however, given that you want to be learning from very small numbers of observations, I'd be tempted to go with a full Bayesian model. This will also let you neatly update parameters after each non-suspicious observation. Inference in these distributions is very easy, with conjugate priors for \lambda and \theta and analytic predictive distributions, so it won't be difficult if you're familiar with these kinds of model at all.

Comment: I worked upon generating a set of features and developed simple statistical method to identify difference in browsing pattern by calculating absolute deviation from central tendency, as of now I wonder about its accuracy since I haven't tested results so far.

I will go by your suggestion of Bayesian approach, but I am pretty naive when it comes to specialized methods other than basic statistical techniques. Can you provide me some sources where I can learn from?

Comment: Since you mention your professor, I'm going to assume you're a student and have access to text books. If so, I like Kevin Murphy's "Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective", which will cover the fundamentals of Bayesian inference and has a lot of practical examples. Depending on statistical literacy, the bible for me is Gelman et al's Bayesian Data Analysis, but you'll need a fairly strong background to get a lot out of that.

Comment: Yes, I am CS Undergrad so I will just look them up in library or amazon. Thanks for the help I'll try my best to make most out of it.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use an unsupervised learning method such as a Self-Organizing Map (SOM, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map). Train the SOM on data representing expected/normal user behavior and then see how well the candidate data set fits the trained map. Keywords to search for in conjunction with "Self-organizing maps" might be "novelty/anomaly/intrusion detection" (turns up e.g. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.2616&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

You should think about whether fraudulent use-cases can be modeled in advance (in which case you can train detectors specifically for them) or whether only deviations from normal behavior are of interest.

Comment: Yes, even my professor advised me in trying SOM, since fraudulent browsing pattern are highly inefficient to model, I am interested in calculating the deviation from normal behavior and may be rank it over suspicion level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start simple, implement a [cosine similarity measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). This would allow you to define a set of "good" vectors. The current user's activity could be compared to the good vectors. If you cannot retrieve a good vector, then the activity is flagged.

Comment: Nice solution, would have to pick up the books again to completely understand it. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to dig deeper, check the literature on intrusion detection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system